# PowerDesigner 15 - Generated code - Serialization - C# - How to generate the [XmlInclude] attribute?

Tags: c#, serialization, powerdesigner

I'm using PowerDesigner 15 and I would like the code generated for each serializable class contains the "[XmlInclude(typeof (CHILD_OBJ))]" attribute that describes child objects.

How could I do, please ?

Best Regards,
Cyrille

Comment: Note: if you can't figure out how to do it via the designer, you can also use either "partial classes", or a custom xml-serializer-overrides (the first is preferable)

Comment: OK, using a partial class is a solution, indeed. Thanks for your  answer.